# Safari sort() function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

Why does my code not work correctly in the Safari browser on Iphone 6 ios 10 and above. In the support table, all values used in the code are supported! The code works everywhere except this device. For my data i use Wilddog it same work as Firebase. Array look like {name: 'Some', like: 2, fav_count: 5 }, {name: 'Some2', like: 3, fav_count: 4 },  {name: 'Some3', like: 3, fav_count: 4 }. Something wrong going on sort() function;

```
  var obj = $wilddogObject(ref); // get data from server 

            obj.$loaded()
                .then(function(data) {

                    var _extends = Object.assign || function(target) {
                        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                            var source = arguments[i];
                            for (var key in source) {
                                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } }
                        return target; };
                    var moments = _.map(data, function(val, id) {
                        return _extends({}, val, {
                            id: id
                        });
                    });


                    $scope.ratePlaces = _.map(moments, function(place) {
                        // console.log(place);
                        if (place != null) {
                            if (place.like != undefined) {
                                function rating(like, favs) {
                                    var parseFavs = parseInt(favs);
                                    var parseLike = parseInt(like);
                                    var newRate = parseLike * 0.5 + parseFavs;
                                    return newRate;
                                }
                                place.rate = rating(place.like, place.fav_count);
                            }
                        }
                        return place
                    })
                    console.log($scope.ratePlaces);
                    list($scope.ratePlaces)
                })




            function list(r) {
                r.shift();
                r.shift();
                r.shift();
                r.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.rate != null || a.rate != undefined || a.rate != 'daylife' || !a.name) {
                        return a.rate - b.rate;
                    } else {}

                })
                r.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.rate != null || a.rate != undefined || a.rate != 'daylife' || !a.name) {
                        let rateA = a.rate;
                        let rateB = b.rate;
                        if (rateA < rateB) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (rateA > rateB) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }

                });
                $scope.posts = r.reverse();
```

Comment: what is the result you are getting on all the devices and in the device where it's failing? Can you add that in the question.

Comment: What are you expecting? Firstly it doesn't look like the objects even have a `rate` property, and secondly a `sort` method should always return something